# Swift: "failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable initializer" vs. default parameters

Tags: swift, initializer, failable

If I declare

```
public class A: NSObject {
    public class X { }
    public init?(x: X? = nil) { }
}
```

all is fine. When using it like `let a = A()`, the initializer is called as expected.

Now, I'd like to have the nested class `X` private, and the parameterized `init` as well (has to be, of course). But a simple `init?()` should stay publicly available as it was before. So I write

```
public class B: NSObject {
    private class X { }
    private init?(x: X?) { }
    public convenience override init?() { self.init(x: nil) }
}
```

But this gives an error with the `init?()` initializer: *failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable initializer* with the overridden initializer being the `public init()` in `NSObject`.

How comes I can effectively declare an initializer `A.init?()` without the conflict but not `B.init?()`?

Bonus question: Why am I not allowed to override a non-failable initializer with a failable one? The opposite is legal: I can override a failable initializer with a non-failable, which requires using a forced `super.init()!` and thus introduces the risk of a runtime error. To me, letting the subclass have the failable initializer feels more sensible since an extension of functionality introduces more chance of failure. But maybe I am missing something here – explanation greatly appreciated.

Comment: `override` implies a method with the same signature in the superclass. However there is no `init?` in `NSObject`

Comment: @vadian: Yes, but omitting the `override` produces the error message `overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword`, so it counts as overriding anyway. Fix-it is inserting `override`, giving the other error.
Moreover, I am allowed to override a failable init with a non-failable, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I solved the problem for me:

I **can** declare

```
public convenience init?(_: Void) { self.init(x: nil) }
```

and use it like

```
let b = B(())
```

or even

```
let b = B()
```

— which is logical since its signature is (kind of) different, so no overriding here. Only using a `Void` parameter and omitting it in the call feels a bit strange… But the end justifies the means, I suppose. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I found this very useful for a Realm db model where I had just a couple of managed object classes that should never be initialised with empty contents, only with a full list of values. With this form I could still call the Realm Object constructor  init(value: Any) as I could use the value label to distinguish the superclass initialiser from my failable one

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of fiddling I think I understand. Let's consider a protocol requiring this initializer and a class implementing it:

```
protocol I {
    init()
}

class A : I {
    init() {}
}
```

This gives the error: "Initializer requirement 'init()' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in non-final class 'A'". This makes sense, as you could always declare a subclass of `A` that doesn't inherit that initializer:

```
class B : A {
    // init() is not inherited
    init(n: Int) {}
}
```

So we need to make our initializer in `A` `required`:

```
class A : I {
    required init() {}
}
```

Now if we look at the `NSObject` interface we can see that the initializer is **not** `required`:

```
public class NSObject : NSObjectProtocol {
    [...]
    public init()
    [...]
}
```

We can confirm this by subclassing it, adding a different initializer and trying to use the normal one:

```
class MyObject : NSObject {
    init(n: Int) {}
}

MyObject() // Error: Missing argument for parameter 'n:' in call
```

Now here comes the weird thing: We *can* extend `NSObject` to conform to the `I` protocol, even though it doesn't require this initializer:

```
extension NSObject : I {} // No error (!)
```

I honestly think this is either a bug or a requirement for ObjC interop to work (EDIT: It's a bug and already fixed in the latest version). This error shouldn't be possible:

```
extension I {
    static func get() -> Self { return Self() }
}

MyObject.get()
// Runtime error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class '__lldb_expr_248.MyObject'
```

Now to answer your actual question:

In your second code sample, the compiler is right in that you cannot override a non-failable with a failable initializer.

In the first one, you aren't actually overriding the initializer (no `override` keyword either), but instead declaring a new one by which the other one can't be inherited.

Now that I wrote this much I'm not even sure what the first part of my answer has to do with your question, but it's nice to find a bug anyways.

I suggest you to do this instead:

```
public convenience override init() { self.init(x: nil)! }
```

Also have a look at the [`Initialization` section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) of the Swift reference.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The underlying problem is that the initializer of my subclass **can** fail since there are external resources involved (`NSCoding`…), so it is (kind of) necessary to test if the initializer was successful. But, please have a look at my "PS" addendum using a `Void` parameter.

Comment: Note that the bug your describe above (`protocol I { init() }` followed by `extension NSObject : I { }`) _does_ yield an error in Swift 3.0-dev (_error: initializer requirement '`init()`' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in non-final class '`NSObject`'_), so I guess its been fixed.